# VPN connection to AWS, when disrupted the server is unresponsive

Tags: windows-server-2008, vpn, amazon-web-services

I’ve got a Windows Server 2008 VM running in AWS. The server maintains a VPN connection to a server in my office for the purposes of synchronizing a Database. Currently using the Cisco AnyConnect VPN client but have also tried others (Shrewsoft).

When the VPN connection is disrupted (either because our in-house router is reconfigured & rebooted for something unrelated, for the ISP has an issue) it appears to also take down the primary virtual network adapter that connects it to Amazon and the outside world.  I suspect this is because the cloud server doesn’t have a real physical network adapter, it is a virtual adapter that is routed through several layers of Amazon’s network infrastructure before it is exposed to the outside world as a public static IP address.

All of the VPN connection tools tried suffer from this same behavior: after establishing a VPN connection, if that virtual adapter loses connectivity, the machine becomes totally unresponsive to any network traffic.  Even Amazon’s management tools cannot communicate with it except to hard reboot it through the hypervisor.

Any clues on how we could resolve this, or is VPN a dead end in this case..?

Answer (score 0):

My ideas for this problem:

1. OpenVPN. I have used it as a server on Linux only but never had these problems (it's available for Windows, too). The client connections break, the clients reconnect. That's it.
2. A watchdog script: Keep a script/program running which checks ever minute or so whether connectivity is still there. If not, restart the VPN software.
3. "Hardware": Get an additional vserver, for optimal performance from AWS, too, or cheaper from somewhere else. Run a, ehm, another OS on that. Then you have a stable connection to your sensitive Windows server and can use a more flexible connection from the other vserver to your office. It may not even be necessary to route all your traffic through this box. Probably you can have more than one VPN interface on your Windows server. If the normal one is broken then you can connect via the fallback vserver and hopefully restart the broken interface that way.